# Male and Female duties and responsibilities

Tags: halacha, torah-study, women

The Torah indeed outlines distinct roles and responsibilities for men and women. However, the concept of "bitul Torah" traditionally pertains primarily to men. In my understanding, this suggests that men should minimize time away from Torah study, which is why esteemed scholars dedicate themselves to learning continuously.

On the other hand, women are not subject to the same concept of "bitul Torah" in the same sense. If a woman has free time, she is generally free to utilize it as she wishes, as long as her activities do not conflict with other Torah-related obligations?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the concept of  bitul Torah is not applicable to women in the same way as it is for men. The following should be considered.

[Rav Yaakov Ariel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Ariel) [writes](https://www.inn.co.il/news/342827) that:

> גם האדם עצמו חייב להיות שותף בבניין אישיותו. מבחינה זו, יום של ביטול תורה הוא חור באישיותה של האישה, ויש להתייחס אליו במידה מסוימת כ"ביטול תורה", אף שאינו "ביטול תורה" במשמעות המקורית של המושג. אין כאן ביטול בידע התורני, אך יש כאן ביטול באישיותה הרוחנית של האישה. A day of bitul Torah [wasting time one could spend learning] is a hole in the character of a woman, and one should relate to it, to some extent, like [the halachic category of] bitul Torah, even though it is not bitul Torah in its original sense. **There is no bitul of [obligatory] Torah knowledge, but there is bitul regarding the spiritual character of the woman.**

See [this article](https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/studies-halakha/women-and-mitzvot/women-learning-torah-iv-what-study). So, according to this explanation by Rav Ariel, bitul Torah is applicable to a woman in the spiritual way.

The Gemara in [Sotah 21a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.21a.12?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that the merit of Torah study is indirect for a woman. The Gemara says:

> Granted, she is not commanded to study Torah herself; however, in reward for causing their sons to read the Written Torah and to learn the Mishna, and for waiting for their husbands until they come home from the study hall, don’t they share the reward with their sons and husbands?

Answer (score 0):

Women are not obligated to study Torah directly, as men are. However, that does not detract from the value of their studying Torah. In fact, the female mind is more apt to review and contain information, so Torah is naturally retained in their minds with some effort, while men have to actively push themselves to retain the information.
TL;DR: While women are not obligated to directly study Torah, and can spend their free time with other things, their Torah study is still precious.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site, see in particular the focus on sourcing your answers. Great to have you learn with us!